# The iconography of Laddu Gopal's soles

Tags: krishna

More questions about the iconography of the young Krishna, this time in his *Laddu Gopal* *swaroop*, which I believe is a traditional image of *Bal Gopal* in Rajasthan, MP and other parts of India.

Here is the gift I received which prompted the question -- [the young Krishna frozen in time, *sakshat* accepting the offerings of the young Raghunandan Das](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEzpFFpY7og):

[image]

My curiosity is about the icons on the soles of the Lord's feet. Here is his left foot, for example:

[image]

There are, what appear to be, the moon, a triangle, a swastika, a recumbent "E" and a bunch of grapes. What do they mean?

Similarly, here is the right foot:

[image]

This is little rougher, but essentially there is still the triangle, the "E" and the swastika, but now we have the sun instead of the moon, and an arrow.

Would love to understand what all these symbols signify.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Everything does not correspond. I have marked with red circle what seemed unexpected and ? mark where I am not sure.

Thanks.

Referene : https://iskcondesiretree.com/group/krishnaconsciousness/forum/topics/the-marks-on-the-lotus-feet-of-lord-krishna